# Find a linear run-time strategy to place all records for females before any records for males?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

3. Some problems related to sorting can be solved in less than the Θ(n log n) lower bound of sorting. Consider the following scenario. A set of N records containing personnel records has a field indicating gender, male or female. Find a linear run-time strategy to place all records for females before any records for males. That is, females will be at the front of the list and males at the end.

Comment: There is no question in your question. Where are you stuck? What ideas do you have?

Comment: Very keen observation.  I wonder what the first two were.

Comment: You just copied the problem from your assignment together with it's number... Where are your efforts? Don't be so lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite easy, similar to quicksort linear phase.

```
boolean[] arr; //array of males/females, true=male, false=female
int pivotLeft = 0;
int pivotRight = array.length-1;

while (pivotLeft < pivotRight){
    if (arr[pivotRight] == true){
      pivotRight--;
    } else if(arr[pivotLeft] == false){
      pivotLeft++;
    } else {
      boolean temp = arr[pivotLeft];
      arr[pivotLeft] = arr[pivotRight];
      arr[pivotRight] = temp;
      pivotLeft++;
      pivotRight--;
    }
}
```

In this case you are pointing at the two position in array. The right is pointing into male section, the left into the female section.

In my code you are moving the right pointer to the left one, if you find male in the right position - which means he belongs there, so you can move on. The same in other direction applies for left pointer.

When you find male in female section and female in male section, you switch them and then continue.

Comment: the code is okay , but please provide the explanation as is what i need.

Comment: thank you its quite  helpful

Comment: @danielmwangi - then please accept answer (it is the "Nike" button near the score of my answer)

Comment: Just a clarification , being to find a linear run time strategy what is it

Comment: @danielmwangi - it means that if you have input of size N (in your case number of males and females), you are able to finish it in one "run", therefore it has O(N) complexity, which is called linear. If you have for cycle in another for cycle, the complexity is usually O(N^2), therefore not linear.

Comment: ,thank you in advance. i now understand